# Talend - generating n multiple rows from 1 row

Tags: java, row, etl, talend

**Background:** I'm using Talend to do something (I guess) that is pretty common: generating multiple rows from one. For example:

`ID | Name | DateFrom   | DateTo`

`01 | Marco| 01/01/2014 | 04/01/2014`

...could be split into:

`new_ID | ID | Name  | DateFrom   | DateTo`

`01     | 01 | Marco | 01/01/2014 | 02/01/2014`

`02     | 01 | Marco | 02/01/2014 | 03/01/2014`

`03     | 01 | Marco | 03/01/2014 | 04/01/2014`

The number of outcoming rows is dynamic, depending on the date period in the original row.

**Question:** how can I do this? Maybe using tSplitRow? I am going to check those periods with tJavaRow. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming those are dd-MM-yyyy format dates? This isn't actually a common thing to do and I'm struggling to think of a (good) reason to normalise the example data in this way but I have a few ideas about how to do it.

Comment: Date format is italian one, and it's not a problem. I need to do this because the original record looks like an aggregated one despite my destination db. However I'm curious about your ideas :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on the answer given by Balazs Gunics

Your first part is to calculate the number of rows one row will become, easy enough with a date diff function on the to and from dates

[image: overall view]

### [image: calculate number of rows per row]

---

Part 2 is to pass that value to a tFlowToIterate, and pick it up with a tJavaFlex that will use it in its start code to control a for loop:

tJavaFlex start:

```
int currentId = (Integer)globalMap.get("out1.id");
String currentName = (String)globalMap.get("out1.name");
Long iterations = (Long)globalMap.get("out1.iterations");
Date dateFrom = (java.util.Date)globalMap.get("out1.dateFrom");

for(int i=0; i<((Long)globalMap.get("out1.iterations")); i++) {
```

Main

```
  row2.id = currentId;
  row2.name = currentName;
  row2.dateFrom = TalendDate.addDate(dateFrom, i, "dd");
  row2.dateTo = TalendDate.addDate(dateFrom, i+1, "dd");
```

End

```
}
```

and sample output:

```
1|Marco|01-01-2014|02-01-2014
1|Marco|02-01-2014|03-01-2014
1|Marco|03-01-2014|04-01-2014
2|Polo|01-01-2014|02-01-2014
2|Polo|02-01-2014|03-01-2014
2|Polo|03-01-2014|04-01-2014
2|Polo|04-01-2014|05-01-2014
2|Polo|05-01-2014|06-01-2014
2|Polo|06-01-2014|07-01-2014
2|Polo|07-01-2014|08-01-2014
2|Polo|08-01-2014|09-01-2014
2|Polo|09-01-2014|10-01-2014
2|Polo|10-01-2014|11-01-2014
2|Polo|11-01-2014|12-01-2014
2|Polo|12-01-2014|13-01-2014
2|Polo|13-01-2014|14-01-2014
2|Polo|14-01-2014|15-01-2014
2|Polo|15-01-2014|16-01-2014
2|Polo|16-01-2014|17-01-2014
2|Polo|17-01-2014|18-01-2014
2|Polo|18-01-2014|19-01-2014
2|Polo|19-01-2014|20-01-2014
2|Polo|20-01-2014|21-01-2014
2|Polo|21-01-2014|22-01-2014
2|Polo|22-01-2014|23-01-2014
2|Polo|23-01-2014|24-01-2014
2|Polo|24-01-2014|25-01-2014
2|Polo|25-01-2014|26-01-2014
2|Polo|26-01-2014|27-01-2014
2|Polo|27-01-2014|28-01-2014
2|Polo|28-01-2014|29-01-2014
2|Polo|29-01-2014|30-01-2014
2|Polo|30-01-2014|31-01-2014
2|Polo|31-01-2014|01-02-2014
```

Comment: Yep, this was my exact thought process. Nicely done and I like the use of screenshots to further explain parts of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tJavaFlex to do this.

If you have a small amount of columns the a tFlowToIterate -> tJavaFlex options could be fine.

In the begin part you can start to iterate, and in the main part you assign values to the output schema. If you name your output is row6 then:

```
row6.id = (String)globalMap.get("id");
```

and so on.

Comment: You're right in that it will probably need a tJavaFlex to do this but you should add more detail to this answer as it currently doesn't solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I came here as I wanted to add all `context` parameters into an Excel data sheet. So the solution bellow works when you are taking 0 input lines, but can be adapted to generate several lines for each line in input.

The design is actually straight forward:

```
tJava –trigger-on-OK→ tFileInputDelimited  → tDoSomethingOnRowSet
  ↓                          ↑
[write into a CSV]     [read the CSV]
```

And here is the kind of code structure usable in the tJava.

```java
try {
  StringBuffer wad = new  StringBuffer();
  
  wad.append("Key;Nub"); // Header
  context.stringPropertyNames().forEach(
    key -> wad.
      append(System.getProperty("line.separator")).
      append(key + ";" + context.getProperty(key) ) 
  );
  
  // Here context.metadata contains the path to the CSV file
  FileWriter output = new FileWriter(context.metadata);
  output.write(wad.toString());
  output.close();
} catch (IOException mess) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred.");
  mess.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course if you have a set of rows as input, you can adapt the process to use a tJavaRow instead of a tJava.

You might prefer to use an Excel file as an on disk buffer, but dealing with this file  format asks more work at least the first time when you don’t have the Java libraries already configured in Talend. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) might help you if you nonetheless chose to go this way.